# Getting key from returned array

Tags: php

I'm working in WooCommerce, but my question is related to basic PHP `foreach` statements.

I have a function that returns a multidimensional array.  The topmost dimension, the key string is what I need. If you've familiar, `$order->get_items();`.

The `order_item_id` is stored as the key like this:

```
'488' => Array( /* Array stuffs */ )
```

That `488` is what I need.  It wouldn't be a problem if the function I'm working with's `foreach` statement was:

```
foreach ($items as $k => $v)
```

Where I could just use `$k`, but it's set up as:

```
foreach ($items as $item)
```

Is there a way to set the value of the key in the array and pass it along as a parameter?

UPDATE:

Here is the function as it works.

```
foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = $order->get_product_from_item($item);
    $gc_enabled = get_post_meta($product->id, 'ignite_gift_enabled', true);
    if ( ! $gc_enabled)
        continue;
    $coupon_prefix = get_post_meta($product->id, '_coupon_prefix', true);
    if ( ! $coupon_prefix)
        $coupon_prefix = '';
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $item['qty']; $x++) { 
        $new_coupon = $this->adjust_voucher( $coupon_prefix, $mode, $msg_details, $order_id, $order_item_id, $product->id );
    }
}
```

`$order_items` is an array of items, the keys of which I need to pass along to other functions referenced, specificaly `adjust_voucher`.

Comment: I couldn't understand why can't foreach ( $items as $item ) be changed to foreach ( $items as $k => $item )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the foreach syntax to be `foreach($items as $key => $item)`.  This would give you access to `$key` while not impacting any existing code in the loop which relies on `$item`.

Comment: I tried that, but there are values that are retrieved with `$item['foo']`.  I tried setting it to `$v['foo']`, but it broke.

Comment: @tPlummer Why would you change to `$v['foo']` if in your foreach you still have `$key => $item`? There should be no need at all to change any variable names inside the loop. Perhaps you should add more code context in your question and show specifically where you have such a problem.

Comment: Because The foreach is `foreach($order_items as $item): ... for( $x=1;  $x <= $item['qty']; $x++ )

Comment: @tPlummer Yes.  I am suggesting you change that line to `foreach($order_items as $key => $item)`  that would give you access to the key for each item inside the loop.

Comment: Got it.  Issue wasn't with my code by some where else when they referenced the param.  Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty approach. Would be expensive if you have a large array -- but otherwise it would work.

```
$items = $order->get_items();
array_walk($items, function(&$v, $i) { $v['id'] = $i; });
```

This code adds another key to the array called `id` and assigns it the current key value.

Requires PHP 5.4 +

**Example**

```
$arr = array(
    486 => array(
        'name' => 'Bob',
    ),
    500 => array(
        'name' => 'Sam',
    ),
);

array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $i) { $v['id'] = $i; });

print_r($arr);
```

**Example Result**

```
Array ( 
    [486] => Array ( 
        [name] => Bob 
        [id] => 486 
    ) 
    [500] => Array ( 
        [name] => Sam 
        [id] => 500 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: What is that `$i`?  I seen it in other functions, but figured it was just a common parameter character.

Comment: In this example `$i` is the key of the current item being passed. `function(&$value, $key) {}` if you rename them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values in your array (if needed up the call stack)

> I tried that, but there are values that are retrieved with
>   $item['foo']. I tried setting it to $v['foo'], but it broke.

```
foreach( $items as $key => &$item ) {
    $item['id'] = $key;

    /* $item now looks like
     * [ 'id' => ...,
     *   ... ]
     */

} unset( $item ); //Needed otherwise references can become complicated
```

Comment: Can you expand on 'unset( $item ); //Needed otherwise references can become complicated' I dont think it makes much sense